# virtualization, guest Network settings error

Tags: 10.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have the following situation, I have a virtualization environment, the host is Ubuntu

Host information:

```
uname -a 
Linux asic 2.6.32-38-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:12:07 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

mii-tool
eth0: negotiated 1000baseT-FD flow-control, link ok
eth1: negotiated 1000baseT-FD flow-control, link ok
eth2: no link
eth3: no link
```

and when executing ethtool command also works perfectly ,

guests information:

```
uname -a 
Linux questa.silminds.com 2.6.18-128.el5 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 11:41:38 EST 2008 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

mii-tool
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth0' failed: Operation not supported no MII interfaces found

ethtool

Settings for eth0:
No data available
```

and when i try to set the network card interface settings using

```
 ethtool -s etho speed 1000 duplex full 
 Cannot get current device settings: No such device
  not setting speed
  not setting duplex
```

some details :

> host is ubuntu 10.04 LTS
>   kvm version is version 0.12.3 (qemu-kvm-0.12.3)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem you're trying to resolve is, but this looks like part of your problem:

```
ethtool -s etho speed 1000 duplex full
              ^
              |
           eth0
```

Zero =/= 'oh'